# any.do system wide "reminder dialog" how to?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Any.Do Style "Reminder" Dialog... (yes, the white one, that is being displayed system wide);
How do I do this?

I start an ACTIVITY X with **translucent theme**, so I need to start it with the Flag **"NEW_TASK"**
and "**singleTask"** in order to not have the previous ACTIVITY N in the background.

**Now I want to do the following:**

When the **home button or back button** is pressed on this ACTIVITY X, I don't want to have it in the "backstack" anymore. Like its gone. So when the app is launched from the launcher (or task switcher) again, it should bring you back to a different activity (ACTIVITY N).

*What it does right now:
When selecting the app from the launcher again, this particular ACTIVITY X, that should be gone (yes, I am calling finish() in onPause()) comes back alive... always.*

How do I archieve this?

**EDIT:**
Some code:

```
<activity 
               android:name=".ActivityX"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
               android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:launchMode="singleInstance"
               android:noHistory="true"
               ></activity>
```

And the intent that calls this activity x:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityX.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

**Just an idea:**
Is it better to start a service instead that pop ups a dialog? Because this is actually the behaviour that I want to "simulate" but system wide...

Comment: in the `onPause` just call `finish()` on the activity

Comment: I do this. But this just hides the activity. The one before is not coming back when clicking the app icon again.

Comment: if you are pressing the back button and the activity is still present when you launch it again then there is something wrong because the back button and calling finish() both pop the backstack

Comment: maybe it's because of the "NEW TASK" Flag ?

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing startactivity(intent). just after that do a finish()...This will finish the activity and no more present in the stack.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not true. Finish() does not remove the activity from backstack. I want not to start a new activity from this one. When it gets paused, it should never come back alive.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:noHistory="true" to the Activity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've tried. Does not work. Even setting a flag in the intent itself:   `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

Comment: You are overcomplicating things. Try removing all the other stuffs and just use this flag.

Comment: I need the NEW_TASK flag in order to get rid of the previous "activity n" because its not a "system wide overlay" otherwise.

Comment: We can create a system wide overlay window. Have a look at this test app. https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Tapjacking/Jackalope

Comment: Yeah because it's a transparent  system overlay which catches all inputs. You can make it transparent and wrap your contents to not cover the entire screen.